# ArcMap 10.2.1 issues diffferent SQL than 10.0 for "Select by location"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, select-by-location

I have a large point layer and I'm doing a "Select by Location" to select all points that intersect a specific selected polygon from a polygon table.

In ArcMap 10.0 the SQL that was executed was basically the following:

1. Stick the se_rowid of the polygon into the sde_logfile_data table
2. Select all points that intersect the polygon

In ArcMap 10.2 the SQL is an alternating sequence of:

1. Insert the rowids of 10000 points into the sde_logfile_data table
2. Select count(distinct sde_row_id) from sde_log_table where logfile_data_id = ...

   i.e., sde_logfile_data keeps getting inserted into and the subsequent selects take longer and longer.  ArcMap ends up stalling and I have to kill it.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: That sounds like an internal problem. I suggest it's time to contact Esri support as there's nothing a user can do to modify the selection behavior of ArcMap Select by Location.